# OpenID retrofitting and can I trust where sensitive data is involved?

Tags: security, openid

I am considering adding OpenID to our customer facing admin and control panel areas...

**1 - Associating OpenID's With Existing Accounts**

For customers that already have accounts with us, I'm thinking they would need to login using their existing account number that we issue and then I'd have a mechanism to associate their OpenID with that account in their account management area (call it 'OpenID Manager' for the sake of argument).

In the 'OpenID Manager', presuming the user already has an OpenID, would I authenticate the user against their OpenID then associate with our generated account number for future OpenID logins (assuming that they authenticated ok)?

**2 - Sensitive Data**

Although we don't store full credit card data in our DB there is other data that is sensitive, invoices, domain reg details etc. After reading this article http://idcorner.org/2007/08/22/the-problems-with-openid/ I'm a little cautious about the idea of using OpenID in this way, what's the general consensus with you folks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that a lot of the arguments against OpenID are either made out of ignorance or by people with an axe to grind.

For example, the document you link to complains that identifying yourself with a URI is "dehumanising and more than a little frightening".  Is that a legitimate complaint, or something written by somebody desperate to find things to complain about?

The two major things that get brought up are phishing and compromised accounts and these arguments have been rehashed so many times, it's hard to take somebody seriously if they bring them up yet again with no new points to make.

Phishing protection depends on the provider.  Some providers offer much better security than typical websites ever would.  Some providers just offer the typical username and password.  Either way, if an account is compromised, that's something between the user and their provider, it's not your concern.  You don't worry that the end-user has a keylogger installed on their computer, do you?  That's because their local security isn't your responsibility, even though it might be used to gain access to their account.  Likewise with OpenID - its security is not your responsibility.

If you compromise an OpenID, it gives you access to more than a single website.  Sure, but the same is true for email.  Just say you've forgotten your password, and you get sent a new one.  You now have access to every account they've registered with that email address.

OpenID is no worse than the status quo, and it's significantly better in many circumstances, especially for informed users.  If you are still wary of it, then just make it optional, so only the informed users use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd allow the registration of *multiple* OpenIDs with a particular account. That's a nice feature to have because it allows users to migrate between OpenIDs should the need ever arise.

---

That said, the idcorner link raises a good point. I think he massively overblows the security issue and makes many idiotic assumptions about how OpenID providers work, but that OpenID really isn't intended to replace all forms of user authentication. It's designed to make it easy for "drive-by" users to interact with a site with some form of basic authentication.

- Ever been to somebody's blog, want to post a comment, but first you have to step through a 3-page registration? OpenID solves that problem.
- Want to post a quick bug report on a public tracker but need an account first? OpenID to the rescue.
- Want to store sensitive proprietary data in a web-accessible way and provide access only to people who are trusted? OpenID is *not* the solution.